# Find differences between 2 HTML files

Tags: php, diff

Is there a way to display differences between two HTML documents?

There is a PHP class called `daisdiff`, but it has no documentation.  Can anyone show how to use it, or any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to use the pear [Text_Diff](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/docs/latest/li_Text_Diff.html) package, the package come with some class and easy extensible, you can write your own "diff" renderer so it's easy to adapt and a lot more easy then parsing the output of the `diff` command.

here a short code snippet to compare two text files:

```
include_once "Text/Diff.php";
include_once "Text/Diff/Renderer.php";

// define files to compare
$file1 = "data1.txt";
$file2 = "data2.txt";

// perform diff, print output
$diff = &new Text_Diff(file($file1), file($file2));
$renderer = &new Text_Diff_Renderer();
echo $renderer->render($diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a UNIX program called `diff` which is meant just for that purpose. You use it like this:

```
diff -crB file1 file2
```

c stands for context. It shows some extra lines around the changed lines so that you can find them more easily.

r stands for recursive. That way you can specify directories as file1 and file2, with all the files therein being compared to each other, too.

B makes it ignore blank lines and their changes.

Let me go find the Windows solution just in case.

Comment: Oops. Looks like I forgot that PHP bit, eh? Just ignore this, then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure php implementation of diff, http://www.holomind.de/phpnet/diff.src.php.  If you skip to the bottom of the page there is an example of how to use it.